# Text to speech code doesn't work anymore after page reload?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I am trying to add a text to speech button to my website and another button that stops it again. It worked perfectly before until I reloaded the page, then it didn't do anything anymore.

So I tried adding `window.onload=` function but then it just starts reading as soon as I reload the page. but I want it to only read if you click the button and stop when the stop button is pressed. I don't understand what I am doing wrong especially because it used to work sometimes and then it didn't again even when I didn't really change the code.

```html
<script>
  window.speechSynthesis.cancel();

  function textToSpeech() {
    const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    let convert = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
    speech.text = convert;
    speech.volume = 2;
    speech.rate = 1;
    speech.pitch = 1;
    speech.voice = voices[1];
    speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
  }

  function stop() {
    window.speechSynthesis.cancel();
  }
  speakBtn.addEventListener('click', textToSpeech);
  cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', stop);
</script>
<input type="button" id="1200196725" value="Speak" style="float: left; 
background-color:#00a2ab;
display:inline-block;
padding:0.3em 1.2em;
margin:0 0.3em 0.3em 0;
border-radius:2em;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
color:#FFFFFF;">
<input type="button" id="1731941681" value="Stop" style="float: left;background-color:#d4004b;
display:inline-block;
padding:0.3em 1.2em;
margin:0 0.3em 0.3em 0;
border-radius:2em;
box-sizing: border-box;
text-decoration:none;
font-family:'Roboto',sans-serif;
font-weight:300;
color:#FFFFFF;">
<p id="1112939208" style="display:none">
  my text here
</p>
```

Comment: Check the Javascript console in Chrome for errors. Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding eventListeners on buttons that haven't been defined it seems.
Try adding this to your code. (And maybe give them more sensible id's)

```
const speakBtn = document.getElementById('1200196725');
const cancelBtn = document.getElementById('1731941681');
```